# Remove or replace "undefined" string in Google Sheets cells using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My `Google Apps Script` receives data from an `HTML` `form`. If `checkbox` or `radio` buttons in a `fieldset` are not selected, then `undefined` string is displayed in a cell, like this:

[image: "undefined" string in a cell]

---

**How can I remove or replace `"undefined"` string in cells using Google Apps Script?**

---

Here is the relevant part of my `Google Apps Script` code that receives and then writes the `form` data to a `Sheet`:

```
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
  if (typeof e.parameters[header] !== "undefined") {
    return header === "Date" ? new Date() : e.parameters[header].join(", ")
  } else {
    return header === "Date" ? new Date() : e.parameters[header]
  }
})

sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following, attempting to recreate the context around your code snippet to facilitate a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

I edited the inline function within `headers.map()` to achieve what I think you're trying to accomplish.

The logic is as follows:

- If the value is undefined and the field is named "Date", return a new `Date()` object.
- If the value is undefined and the field is not named "Date", return an empty 
  string.
- If the value is defined and is an array, return a string created by joining the values.
- If the value is defined and is not an array, return the value.

In your original code snippet, if the value wasn't an array, it would try to call `join()` and would fail.

```
var VALUES = [
  {
    'Foobar': ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'],
    'Xyzzy': ['Quux'],
    'Name': ['Jane Doe'],
  },
  {
    'Foobar': ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'],
    'Xyzzy': undefined,
    'Name': ['Peter Pan'],
  },
];

function populateCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  for (var i = 0; i < VALUES.length; i++) {
    var e = {parameters: VALUES[i]};

    /** EDITED VERSION OF YOUR CODE SNIPPET STARTS HERE **/

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      if (typeof e.parameters[header] === 'undefined') {
        return header === 'Date' ? new Date : '';
      }

      if (Array.isArray(e.parameters[header])) {
        return e.parameters[header].join(', ')
      } else {
        return e.parameters[header]
      }
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);

    /** EDITED VERSION OF YOUR CODE SNIPPET ENDS HERE **/
  }
}
```